# Web browser (empty) cannot render Bokeh plot after uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda2-5.5.1.0-Windows-x86_64 on Windows 7 machine

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, bokeh

After uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda2-5.5.1.0-Windows-x86_64 on Windows 7 machine, Web browser (empty) does not render Bokeh plots. Python 2.7.14, Bokeh version 0.12.13, Tornado version 4.5.3. from the Spyder, editor tried just the simplest example from Bokeh's page:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
# create a new plot with default tools, using figure
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

# add a circle renderer with a size, color, and alpha
p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=15, line_color="navy", fill_color="orange", fill_alpha=0.5)

show(p) # show the results
```

The code runs with no errors and automatically invokes a browser window but the plot does not get rendered.

Comment: What output is in the browser's javascript console log?

Comment: The browser's javascript console log reports: "Handler function threw an exception: TypeError: This.transport is null.  Stack: send@resource://devtools/shared/base-loader.js -> resource://devtools/server/main.js:1513:5

Comment: None of that is from Bokeh, so I am not sure. Do things work outside spyder?

Comment: Also: ReferenceError: Bokeh is not defined.  Same problem when bokeh  is invoked directly from the Anaconda command line. Trying to open the HTML file generated by bokeh gives same result (nothing in window)

Comment: That means BokehJS is never loaded by your browser. By default it is loaded from a CDN, over the internet, from `cdn.pydata.org`. Are you in an airgapped situation or otherwise without internet connectivity? If so you will need to use "inline" resources.

Comment: Opening the HTML file generated by Bokeh in Notepad++ does show that Bokeh generated all the HTML code to create/define the elements of the plot and associated window on the web page.

Comment: I am using an air-gaped workstation. Can you provide more info/link to "inline" resources?

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the work to render Bokeh plots is done by a JavaScript library, BokehJS. Normally by default this JS library is loaded from the `cdn.bokeh.org` CDN. This requires a working internet connection, however. In airgapped situations, inline resources must be used. This will directly embed BokehJS in output that is generated.

One way is to set the `BOKEH_RESOURCES` environment variable, e.g.

```
BOKEH_RESOURCES=inline python foo.py
```

You could also set this before running `spyder`, or set it in a shell init script so that it is always used by any process.

Setting the environment variable has the advantage that the same code can be used either way, with the value of the `BOKEH_RESOURCES` overriding the default resources. However, it is also possible to specify inline resources in the code itself. One way is to set the `mode` on `output_file`:

```
output_file(mode="inline")
```

There are other ways for other output/embed methods, too. For details see the docs:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html